# How can I display firebase data in a fragment with recyclerview? Kotlin Android Studio

Tags: android, firebase, kotlin, firebase-realtime-database

hello I have an activity that has a navigation bar and fragments inside, in one of my fragments I save data in firebase, I want to get those data and display it in other fragment with recycler view. I watched a tutorial on youtube to do it cuz my teacher didn't teach us anything, the issue is the fragment that was supposed the display the data shows nothing, it's blank but I didn't understand why cuz I'm really new to this, if someone can take a look at my code and help me I would really appreciate it

This is my data class

```
data class Event(var eventName: String, var eventTime:String?=null)
```

This is ViewModel

```
class EventViewModel :ViewModel() {
    private val repository : EventRepository
    private val _allEvents = MutableLiveData<List<Event>>()
    val allEvents : LiveData<List<Event>> = _allEvents

    init {
        repository= EventRepository().getInstance()
        repository.loadEvents(_allEvents)

    }
}
```

This is Repository

```
class EventRepository {

    private val databaseReference: DatabaseReference= FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("PetEvents")

    @Volatile private var INSTANCE : EventRepository ?=null

    fun getInstance() : EventRepository{
        return INSTANCE ?: synchronized(this) {
            val instance = EventRepository()
            INSTANCE=instance
            instance

        }
    }

    fun loadEvents(eventList : MutableLiveData<List<Event>>){

        databaseReference.addValueEventListener(object:ValueEventListener{
            override fun onDataChange(snapshot: DataSnapshot) {
                try {

                    val _eventList : List<Event> = snapshot.children.map { dataSnapshot ->
                    dataSnapshot.getValue(Event::class.java)!!
                    }
                    eventList.postValue(_eventList)
                }
                catch (e: Exception){

                }
            }

            override fun onCancelled(error: DatabaseError) {
                TODO("Not yet implemented")
            }
        })
    }
}
```

This is Adapter

```
class EventAdapter : RecyclerView.Adapter<EventAdapter.MyViewHolder>() {

    private var eventList =ArrayList<Event>()

    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): MyViewHolder {
       val itemView = LayoutInflater.from(parent.context).inflate(
           R.layout.event_item_cell,
           parent, false
       )
        return MyViewHolder(itemView)
    }

    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: MyViewHolder, position: Int) {
        val currentItem = eventList[position]
        holder.eventName.text =currentItem.eventName
        holder.eventTime.text =currentItem.eventTime
    }

    override fun getItemCount(): Int {
        return eventList.size
    }

    fun updateEventList(eventList: List<Event>){

        this.eventList.clear()
        this.eventList.addAll(eventList)
        notifyDataSetChanged()
    }

    class MyViewHolder(itemView: View): RecyclerView.ViewHolder(itemView){
        val eventName :TextView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.txEventName)
        val eventTime :TextView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.txEventTime)

    }

}
```

And this is the fragment I wish to display the data

```
private lateinit var viewModel : EventViewModel
private lateinit var eventRecyclerView: RecyclerView
lateinit var adapter: EventAdapter

class MainFragment : Fragment() {

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)

    }

    override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View? {
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main, container, false)
    }


    override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)

        eventRecyclerView=view.findViewById(R.id.recyclerView)
        eventRecyclerView.layoutManager= LinearLayoutManager(context)
        eventRecyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true)
        adapter = EventAdapter()
        eventRecyclerView.adapter= adapter

        viewModel = ViewModelProvider(this).get(EventViewModel::class.java)

        viewModel.allEvents.observe(viewLifecycleOwner, Observer {
            adapter.updateEventList(it)
        })

    }
}
```

In my fragment xml I put a recycler view, there's no issue about that
And my item cell is a cardview idk if it has anything to with the problem I'm getting tho

Comment: Can you do a logcat at the `onDataChange` . if the data is there or not

Comment: @TicherhazFreePalestine I put something like Log.d("Tag", "The data is here") in onDataChange and It shows up in the logcat so I don't think It's the problem

Comment: can you put log above this line `adapter.updateEventList(it)` for value `it`, does it contain data or not

Comment: @TicherhazFreePalestine I put this there Log.d("Tag2", "It contains data") and it doesn't show in the logcat

Comment: I see... so you know the answer?

Comment: @TicherhazFreePalestine I understand the problem is that it doesn't contain data but idk why it happened, do you know what can I do to solve it? thank you so much for helping me btw

Comment: Since you're using Kotlin, I think that this [resource](https://medium.com/firebase-tips-tricks/how-to-create-an-android-app-using-multiple-firebase-products-in-kotlin-16aade81ffec) will definitely help. Here is the corresponding [repo](https://github.com/alexmamo/FireApp).

Comment: If you want to learn the modern way of creating native UI, I think that this [resource](https://medium.com/firebase-tips-tricks/how-to-make-a-clean-architecture-android-app-using-mvvm-firestore-and-jetpack-compose-abdb5e02a2d8) will definitely help. Here is the corresponding [repo](https://github.com/alexmamo/FirestoreCleanArchitectureApp).

Comment: What exactly in this code doesn't work the way you expect?
Tell us what is wrong with shared code. Do you have any errors?

Comment: @AlexMamo Well, I add data in firebase from a fragment and I want to display those data in another fragment in a recylerview, but when I run the application the fragment doesn' show my data, and no I don't get any error messages. But the person above told me to put log messages and check my logchart, seems like my viewmodel doesn't work properly but I don't know how to solve it. Like, I put log here and it didn't show on the logchart  `viewModel.allEvents.observe(viewLifecycleOwner, Observer {
            Log.d("Tag", "It contains data")
            adapter.updateEventList(it)
        })`

Comment: And thank you I'll take a look at those links